# How to see if time series terms are independent

Tags: time-series, probability, correlation, mathematical-statistics, autocorrelation

I've already read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487265/autocovariance-of-a-given-stochastic-process), however I found it too theoretical for me, since I haven't studied time series yet.

I have a time series that I have gathered from some measurements. At the current point in time, this is all the data I have: $(1, 1.5, 1.7, 0.5, 2, 2.3, 1.6, 1.7, 0.8, 0.4, 1.7, 2, 2.1, 2.5, 1)$ as time will go on, I will gather more data.

I want to see whether the measurament at $t$ is correlated with the measurement at $t-1$. Looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocovariance) seems like I could use Autocovariance. This is defined to be $$Cov[X_s, X_t] = E[X_tX_s] - E[X_s]E[X_t]$$ where $E[X_t]$ is the **mean function**. I still don't know how to calculate this practically. Here is my attempt.

**Mean Function**

To calculate $E[X_t]$ I calculate the mean for every number of past observations

$$E[X_0] = 1$$ $$E[X_1] = \frac{1 + 1.5}{2} =1.25 $$ $$E[X_2] = \frac{1 + 1.5 + 1.7}{3} = 1.4$$ $$E[X_3] = \frac{1 + 1.5 + 1.7 + 0.5}{4} = 1.175$$

$$E[X_4] = \frac{1 + 1.5 + 1.7 + 0.5 + 2}{5} = 1.34$$

And so on. So in general, my intuition of the mean function is $\mu_t = E[X_t] = \frac{X_0 + ...+X_{t}}{t+1}$.

**Covariance**

Suppose I wanted to calculate $Cov[X_2, X_3]$. Then we know $$Cov[X_2, X_3] = E[X_2X_3] - E[X_2]E[X_3]$$ We have the second term from above because $E[X_2]E[X_3] = 1.4  \times 1.175 = 1.645$. Then I need to calculate the first term, again out of intuition I would do the following $$E[X_0X_1] = 1 * 1.5 = 1.5$$
$$E[X_1X_2] = \frac{1 * 1.5 + 1.5 * 1.7}{2} = 2.025$$
$$E[X_2X_3] = \frac{1 * 1.5 + 1.5 * 1.7 + 1.7*0.5}{3} = 1.633$$
$$E[X_3X_4] = \frac{1 * 1.5 + 1.5 * 1.7 + 1.7*0.5 + 0.5*2}{4} = 1.475$$

And so on, so that at the end $$Cov[X_2, X_3] = E[X_2X_3] - E[X_2]E[X_3] = 1.633 - 1.645 = -0.012$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Why are you counting $E[X_t]$ as the mean of all previous observations?

Comment: Because I don't have a probability function to calculate it from. I don't have anything